# Scale Action Bar background image proportionally

Tags: java, android, eclipse, styles, android-actionbar

Im using ActionBar in my Android App, and to customize each of the tabs, i put a background image behing the ActionBar, which looks the following:

[image]

On my phone actually it looks fine, but on other phones it's look very squashed. How can i scale the ActionBar proportionally based on the background's ratio? Are there any solution for this? I had to determine the height in fix DPI because if i leave it out, the ActionBar is not even showing up. My style code is the following right now;

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">

    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/tab_bg</item>
    <item name="android:adjustViewBounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">fitEnd</item>
    <item name="android:height">87dp</item>

</style>
```

Update:

I just do not know where to Mr.T's xml code. Im using the basic android ActionBar, and i have only one xml named menu.xml, but if i put the code into it, no effect.

I tried to style the actionbar with the following, but still, if i do not specify the android:height parameter, the actionbar remains 0 and do not showing up.

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/tab_bg</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/tab_bg</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">matrix</item>
</style>
```

The actionbar still looks like the following on some devices;
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4453K.png

Answer (score -1):

You might do it with either scaleType(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

You use ImageView instead of background placing it as the first layout's element and specify android:scaleType attribute for it:

```
 <RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:src="@drawable/backgrnd"
    android:scaleType="matrix" />

...

rest layout components here

...

 </RelativeLayout>
```

or drawable xml